# AVCaptureDevice focusPointOfInterest doesn't change

Tags: iphone, focus, avcapturedevice

I have an IBAction with this code:

.h file:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device;
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction)focusInfo {
 if (device == nil) {
  device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
 }

 NSLog(@"Camera focus point of interest: %d, %d", device.focusPointOfInterest.x, device.focusPointOfInterest.y);
}
```

This is conneted to button on CustomCameraOverlay. When I am pressing the button while moving the camera nothing changes. The console log is all the  time the same:

```
Camera focus point of interest: 0, 1071644672
```

Why it is not changing while camera is changing focus? What I am doing wrong? I tried also to get property isAdjustingFocus, but it is not changing as well.

I wanted to addObserwer for those properties, but stucked in here, observer won't work if value won't change.

Answer (score 2):

`focusPointOfInterest` is of type `CGPoint`, which consists of`CGFloat`s. Try `%f` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `NSStringFromCGPoint` when logging CGPoint (or other CGxxx structs)

```
NSLog(@"Camera focus point of interest: %@",
        NSStringFromCGPoint(device.focusPointOfInterest);
```